# The variable is empty after inner loop `for`

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop

I know that pipes is proceeding in subshells, but need a little help..
Got the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
first=""
second=""
for item1 in $(ls *.o)
do
    first=`nm $item1 | grep -e '\<U\>' | awk '{print2}'`
    for item2 in $(ls *.o)
    do
        second=`nm $item2 | grep -e '\<T\>' | awk '{print3}'`

        if [ "$first" == "$second" ]; then
            echo "$item1 => $item2 ($second)"
        else
            echo "Error!"
        fi
    done 
done
```

After the script has been executed, i'm receiving the empty $second (in the brackets):

```
print_recursive.o => print_recursive.o ()
print_recursive.o => recfun.o ()
print_recursive.o => recursive.o ()
print_recursive.o => timeout.o ()
```

Would you mind rewrite this code in right order? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to indent properly. Note you have two nested `for`s and the `if/else` is inside them.

Comment: `for ... in *.o`. No need to call `ls` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always strive to come up with a *minimal example*. This problem has nothing to do with loops.

If you have a problem with the variable, check the command which sets it. In this case:

```
second=`nm $item2 | grep -e '\<T\>' | awk '{print3}'`
```

That `awk` command doesn't do anything. I guess you meant `{print $3}`, though that won't solve the problem either, as `nm` will return multiple matching rows. Do you want to compare the two sets? If so, `sort` them first.